# python sava data into txt file

Tags: python, file-handling

I have problem to create a full coding python file handling. I need all data functions in python will be save in txt file. Below is my coding.

```
def getListFromFile(fileName):
 infile = open(fileName,'r')
 desiredList = [line.rstrip() for line in infile]
 infile.close()
 return desiredList   

def main():
 staffRegistration()
 staffLogin()

 regList = getListFromFile("registration.txt")
 createSortedFile(regList, "afterreg.out")
 loginList = getListFromFile("login.txt")
 createSortedFile(userLogin, "afterlogin.out")

 checkFileRegistration()
 checkFileLogin()

def checkFileRegistration():
 print("\nPlease check afterreg.out file")

def checkFileLogin():
 print("\nPlease check afterlogin.out file")

def staffRegistration():
 regList = []
 name = input("Name: ")
 s = int(input("Staff ID (e.g 1111): "))
 regList.append(s)
 s = int(input("Staff IC (without '-'): "))
 regList.append(s)
 s = int(input("Department - 11:IT Dept 12:ACC/HR Dept 13:HOD 41:Top 
 Management (e.g 1/2/3/4): "))
 regList.append(s)
 s = int(input("Set username (e.g 1111): "))
 regList.append(s)
 s = int(input("Set Password (e.g 123456): "))
 regList.append(s)

 f = open("registration.txt",'w')
 f.write(name)
 f.write(" ")
 for info in regList:
    f.write("%li "%info)
 f.close

 f1 = open("afterreg.out",'w')
 f1.writelines("Registration Successful\n\n")
 f1.close()

def staffLogin():
 serLogin = input("\nProceed to login - 1:Login 2:Cancel (e.g 1/2): ")
 if userLogin == "1":
    username = input("\nUsername (e.g 1111): ")
    l = int(input("Password: "))
 if userLogin == "2":
    print("\nLogin cancelled")

 f = open("login.txt",'w')
 f.write(username)
 f.write(" ")
 for info in userLogin:
    f.write("%li "%info)
 f.close

 f1 = open("afterlogin.out",'w')
 f1.writelines("Logged in successful")
 f1.close()

def createSortedFile(listName, fileName):
 listName.sort()
 for i in range(len(listName)):
    listName[i] = listName[i] + "\n"      
    outfile = open(fileName,'a')
    outfile.writelines(listName)

 outfile.close() 

main()
```

Actually, this program should have five requirements. First is `staffRegistration()`, `staffLogin()`, `staffAttendance()`, `staffLeaveApplication()`, `approval()` but I have done for two requirements only and I get stuck at `staffLogin()`. I need every function will be save in txt file (I mean the data in function).

Comment: That's a lot of code! Can you simplify this down into a minimal, complete, and verifiable example?

Comment: and also code indention is not correct.

Comment: What is the problem?  What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

In line 32 you try to convert a String into Integer. Besides, in your main function, you have an unresolved variable `userLogin`.
The other problem is in line 43 (staffLogin function), You want to write a long integer but you pass a string. I have tried to fix your code except for userLogin in main.

```
def getListFromFile(fileName):
 infile = open(fileName,'r')
 desiredList = [line.rstrip() for line in infile]
 infile.close()
 return desiredList

def main():
 staffRegistration()
 staffLogin()

 regList = getListFromFile("registration.txt")
 createSortedFile(regList, "afterreg.out")
 loginList = getListFromFile("login.txt")
 createSortedFile(userLogin, "afterlogin.out")

 checkFileRegistration()
 checkFileLogin()

def checkFileRegistration():
 print("\nPlease check afterreg.out file")

def checkFileLogin():
 print("\nPlease check afterlogin.out file")

def staffRegistration():
 regList = []
 name = input("Name: ")
 s = int(input("Staff ID (e.g 1111): "))
 regList.append(s)
 s = int(input("Staff IC (without '-'): "))
 regList.append(s)
 s = input("Department - 11:IT Dept 12:ACC/HR Dept 13:HOD 41:Top  Management (e.g 1/2/3/4): ")
 regList.append(s)
 s = int(input("Set username (e.g 1111): "))
 regList.append(s)
 s = int(input("Set Password (e.g 123456): "))
 regList.append(s)

 f = open("registration.txt",'w')
 f.write(name)
 f.write(" ")
 for info in regList:
    f.write("%li "%info)
 f.close

 f1 = open("afterreg.out",'w')
 f1.writelines("Registration Successful\n\n")
 f1.close()

def staffLogin():
 userLogin = input("\nProceed to login - 1:Login 2:Cancel (e.g 1/2): ")
 if userLogin == "1":
    username = input("\nUsername (e.g 1111): ")
    l = int(input("Password: "))
 if userLogin == "2":
    print("\nLogin cancelled")

 f = open("login.txt",'w')
 f.write(username)
 f.write(" ")
 for info in userLogin:
    f.write("%s "%info)
 f.close

 f1 = open("afterlogin.out",'w')
 f1.writelines("Logged in successful")
 f1.close()

def createSortedFile(listName, fileName):
 listName.sort()
 for i in range(len(listName)):
    listName[i] = listName[i] + "\n"
    outfile = open(fileName,'a')
    outfile.writelines(listName)

 outfile.close()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems in the `staffLogin()` function. e.g. the result of the first `input()`is bound to `serLogin`, but this should be `userLogin`.

If that is corrected, a password is read from the user, but nothing is ever done with it. Should the password be treated as an integer?

Also, if the user enters `2` at first prompt, the code will not set `username` but it will still try to write `username` to the file. That will raise a `NameError` exception.

Finally, the code attempts to write the characters in `userLogin` to the file as though they are integers. Not only will that not work, it doesn't make sense. Perhaps this should be writing the password to the file?